# Empty POST from jQuery UI Dialog to PHP function with $.post

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui, post

I am having hell of a time trying to figure this one out. Maybe someone can help me here or point me in the right direction.

I have a jQuery UI dialog that pops up when user clicks on an image. The dialog displays a form with 2 drop down windows. "dept" and "group". Group drop down is disabled, until something is selected in the "dept" dropdown menu.

When user selects a department, I do a POST to php function and then enable and populate the group drop down. Simple enough...

```
<select name="dept" id="dept_select" onchange="getDeptGroups(this.value);">
 // Some data here
</select>
```

JS function:

```
function getDeptGroups(dept)
{
       // This alert works and displays department name.
       //alert(dept);

       $.post("/am/ldap/getDepartmentGroups.php", { 
              department: dept },
              function(data){
                    alert(data);
       });
}
```

and finally in php page i just do

```
<? print_r($_POST); ?>
```

and end up with empty array.

```
Array
(
)
```

This happens in both, Chrome and Firefox, however, FireBug clearly shows post data being submitted:

[Screenshot of FireBug showing POST data http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3903355/post.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3903355/post.png)

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: It shows the data is being submitted, but what does it show as the response?

Comment: What do you see if you `print_r($_REQUEST);`

Comment: Have you tried posting from a standard form? i.e. `<form action="/am/ldap/getDepartmentGroups.php" method="post">`

Comment: @thetaiko: i see my session info in the $_REQUEST

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: The form is generated by CodeIgniter. method="POST" is added automatically

Comment: Any difference if you use `jQuery.post()` instead of `$.post()`?  What happens if you use `$.get()` instead of post?

Comment: @thetaiko: `$.get` works fine! I had to massage the get url to work with CodeIgniter, but it does pass `GET` data to the function without a problem...

Comment: Hi. Did you find out what was the problem? I am facing the same problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, verify that the PHP side of things is working as expected. Set up a static form that posts to that page and see what the output is:

```
<form action="/am/ldap/getDepartmentGroups.php" method="post">
  <select name="dept">
    <option value="extern">External</option>
    ...etc
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If you still get a blank array as the output, then there is a problem in PHP and/or the server.

Otherwise, perhaps try using the jQuery ajax function, since calling `post` jsut calls that anyway:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/am/ldap/getDepartmentGroups.php',
  data: { department: dept },
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

EDIT: Ah, you said in a comment you're using CodeIgniter. I believe CI removes the `$_POST` array, you'll need to use `$this->input->post` instead. To get your `department` variable you would write `$this->input->post('department')`

Comment: regular post with submit button works fine, but adding changing `$.post` to `$.ajax` does not change anything. I still get empty `POST`

Comment: `$_POST` works fine in CI, actually. I use it all the time. The reason i am not using `$this->input->post()` in this case is because it can only output individual values, while `$_POST` dumps the entire `POST` array.